# How to access a php variable into external .js(my.js) file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

How can I gain access to a PHP variable from an external javascript (my.js) file? I want to get the dynamic id or class into external js file

**PHP**

```
<div id="tabs<?php echo str_replace(' ', '',$child1['id']); ?>" class="<?php  echo $activetab1; ?> tab-pane">
    <?php if ($child1['children1']) { $category2=$child1['children1'];  ?>
    <ul class="tabs<?php echo str_replace(' ', '',$child1['id']); ?>" id="tabs<?php echo str_replace(' ', '',$child1['id']); ?>" data-count="15">
        <?php foreach ($category2 as $child2) { ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $child2['name']."------------main"; ?>
        </li>
        <?php if ($child2['children9']) { $category9=$child2['children9'];  ?>
        <?php foreach ($category9 as $child9) { ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo $child9['name']; ?>
            <?php echo str_replace(' ', '',$child1['id']); ?>
        </li>
        <?php } } ?>
        <?php }  ?>
    </ul>
    <?php }  ?>
</div>
```

**External JavaScript**

```
var container = $("ul.tabs25"),
count = container.data("count"),
column;

container.children().each(function(index) { 

  if (index % count == 0)
    column = $("<li/>").css({"float": "left", "margin-right": "50px"}).appendTo(container);

  var hello=$(this).appendTo(column);
  console.log(hello);
});
```

I want to dynamically change this `$child1['id']` within JavaScript.

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly. It makes it much easier to read and therefore more likely for people to help you

Comment: its okay? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: *How can I gain access to a PHP variable from an external javascript.* **I want to dynamically change this** `tabs25` **within JavaScript.** What will it be? Access a Variable or change `tabs25`? if the former (access a variable); which variable? is it the $child1['id'] that you want to expose?

Comment: yes its $child1['id']

Answer (score 1):

You can access data from php script in Javascript (I'll use jQuery here) like this

Create input hidden field within you php file like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="myPhpValue" value="<?php echo $myPhpValue ?>" />
in your javascript file:

var myPhpValue = $("#myPhpValue").val();
//From here you can the whaterver you like with you js Value
if(myPhpValue != ''){
//Do something here
}
```

This will do the job

Comment: @mark there are 18-20 $myphpvalue in my code . how to i dynamically access them .

Comment: create 20 input hidden and get the values with jQuery

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is to create an inline script with PHP. Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myid=<?php echo str_replace(' ', '',$child1['id']); ?>;
</script>
```

This way myid is included in the html output of PHP.